# How to count number of entries in several arrays

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  post_id int, tags int[]
);

INSERT INTO posts (post_id, tags) VALUES 
(1, '{1, 2, 3}'), (2, '{3, 2, 4, 5, 7}'),
(3, '{6}'), (4, '{1, 7}'),
(5, '{4, 5, 3}'), (6, '{1, 4, 5}'),
(7, '{5, 6, 7}'), (8, '{7, 8}'),
(9, '{4}'), (0, '{3, 7, 8}');

CREATE TABLE tags (
  tag_id int, name varchar
);

INSERT INTO tags (tag_id, name) VALUES
(1, 'HTML'), (2, 'SQL'), (3, 'JS'),
(4, 'C++'), (5, 'Golang'), (6, 'CSS'),
(7, 'Java'), (8, 'Lua');
```

And I need to get top-5 (name, number) tags by number of references.

I'm familiar with loops, and can iterate through an array. But in this case it's not obvious for me how to combine iterating through each array and through the whole table.

What are the ways of implementing this task?

Comment: Still, interested in other ways of implementing this. Obviously, it's better to use Gordon's variant, but i guess that any other(may be more verbose) ways might be useful for beginners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unnest()` to transform the array into rows.  The rest is then just `join` and aggregation:

```
select t.name, count(*)
from posts p cross join
     unnest(tags) tag join
     tags t
     on t.tag_id = tag
group by t.name
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 5 rows only;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7bf0327edce45dec14114234f4f7c27c) is a db<>fiddle.